# Keep TCP connection keep alive and loop only GET command

Tags: http, tcp, at-command, esp8266

I need to save time in each time connecting to my website and get data.

Here is what I do.

ESP module connects to a home WiFi.

1. `AT+CIPMUX=0` --> response `OK`
2. `AT+CWMODE=1` --> response `OK`
3. `AT+CIPSTART="TCP","http://mysim900.com",80` --> response `connected OK`
4. `AT+CIPSEND=75` --> response --> `>waiting for data to GET or POST`
5. ```
   >GET http://mysim900.com/sw_status.php?status=list_all HTTP/1.0 /r/n/r/n/r/n

   send OK.
   ```

Responds with 200 and receives all bytes from my website. 
And finally

```
connection CLOSED.
```

By repeating steps 3, 4 and 5 I can successfully get the data from my website multiple number of times.
And every time end of step 5 the module says -> `connection CLOSED`.

What I need is not to close the connection each time.
Establishing connection each time consumes time and to re-establish, I need to start from step 3 (`AT+CIPSTART`).

Instead, is there any possible way (any AT command) to stay connected to my site mysim900.com?
And just with one line of AT command which can quickly get data from my website, so that the refresh rate of my code will increase.

Comment: You can't make multiple HTTP requests on a single TCP connection. Each request requires its own connection.

Answer (score 1):

First the request you are issuing is wrong (one `\r\n` too much at the end). And if you want HTTP keep alive with HTTP/1.0 you have to add a `Connection: keep-alive` header. Still, this is only a suggestion to the server that it might keep the connection open. And of course with HTTP keep-alive you need to find the proper end of the response by extracting the content-length because end of connection will no longer work as the end of response.

Comment: actually ESP8266 will accept and send if i use \r\n thrice. once will not work. and another thing where should i mention in the request Connection: keep-alive?? is there any specific AT command or how can i modify the existing request?

Comment: @mutthunaveen: `\r\n` must be given exactly twice: first to signal the end of the current header line and another one to send an empty line and thus mark the end of the HTTP header. And the `Connection: keep-alive\r\n` is part of the HTTP header (which includes the GET line). I recommend that you actually study how HTTP works before using it. There are standards for it: [HTTP/1.0](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1945) and [HTTP/1.1](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616).

Comment: Dear Steffen Ullrich..Thank you for your explanation. now everything makes sense. i will read the mentioned materials and implement. Thank you again.